# Glassfish (Payara) MySQL and Set Context Error

Tags: java, mysql, linux, jpa, glassfish

I am having an issue with a new setup of Glassfish 4.1 (Payara) on a fresh centos box.  Basically I have set all the settings to the same as on my Windows dev machine.  But when I deploy the WAR file and JPA tries to create to tables in MySQL I get the following error for every create statement:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in 
your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT' 
at line 1 PER01000:
```

I have no idea what is causing this but I suspect it is having the knock on effect of preventing JASS from working correctly as well as that appears to be behaving incorrectly but that is for another question.

Every setting in the persistence.xml file is the same as on the dev machine bar the JTA data source and I am using

```
    <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit"
    transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>SNIP</jta-data-source>
    <Snip> 
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I have setup glassfish in the usual way, put the mysql connector into the lib folder and can ping the database without issue from the admin console.  I can also view the home static page of my webapp that doesn't require database access.

I am completely stumped with this as it all worked perfectly on my Windows box and all the settings are the same.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that I need to give some permissions or something to the linux user that glassfish is running under? But I can't think of any as I upload the war to the user home directory they deploy it from there through the glassfish panel and I don't get any permission errors

Comment: add the property `<property name="toplink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>` to your `persitence.xml` and evaluate when this occurs.

Comment: what is your mysql version and what driver is payara using? might be a driver isue.